# Função file() php não pega linha por linha dependendo da terminação

Tags: php, arquivo, newline

Tenho um sistema que está passando por problemas, alguns arquivos são reconhecidos linha por linha, e outros arquivos texto com algumas coisas diferentes ele considera como uma linha só.

Estou utilizando a função `file()` do PHP. O código:

```
<?php
$lines = file("NET3110123.txt");

foreach($lines as $key=>$line){

    echo '#'.$key.": ".$line.'<br /><br />';
}
?>
```

Com esse código ele me retorna:

> `#0: (conteúdo todo...)`

em alguns arquivos mas

> `#0: (linha 1)`
> `#1: (linha 2)`
> `#2: ...`

corretamente em outros, que é o que preciso.

Comment: Está usando um mac?

Comment: Estou usando Linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ocorre que em diferentes sistemas operacionais (que provavelmente é o caso aí) as quebras de linha são representadas por caracteres diferentes (ou combinação deles).

As quebras são

- `\r` 0x13 CR (Carriage Return - incomum o uso individual)
- `\n` 0x10 LF (Line Feed em Linux e similares)
- ambos `\r\n` CRLF (no Windows é o formato usual)

(LFCR até o momento não vi em uso prático)

Há uma diretiva no PHP para detecção automática do tipo de quebra de linha, que pode ajudar em origens mistas (desde que você não misture mais de um tipo no mesmo arquivo):

**[auto_detect_line_endings](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings)**

Uso:

```
<?php
   ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

   $lines = file("NET3110123.txt");

   foreach($lines as $key=>$line){
      echo '#'.$key.": ".$line.'<br /><br />';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Woww.. Deu certo @Bacco ... Muito obrigado!